# ¿Por qué es ambigua la llamada a este método?

Tags: c++, clase, herencia, virtualización, struct

Buenas, en el siguiente código se intenta llamar a una función f de la clase D, que hereda de B y C, en esta clase hay un sólo método f() ya que no hay duplicados al heredar virtualmente y un método f(int), los métodos se llaman igual pero reciben distinto tipo de parámetro, ¿por qué es ambiguo entonces?

```
struct A {
    void f() {}
};

struct B: virtual A {
    void f(int i) {}
};

struct C: virtual A {
    void f() {}
};

struct D: B, C {

};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.f(5); //ambiguo
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En C++ hay un concepto poco conocido que es el de ocultación:

```
struct A
{
  void func()
  { }
};

struct B : A
{
  void func(int)
  { }
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  b.func(5); // ok
  b.func(); // error
}
```

Si se declara una función con el mismo nombre y diferente firma en una clase derivada, las correspondientes funciones de la clase padre dejan de estar disponibles salvo que se invoquen de forma explícita:

```
int main()
{
  B b;
  b.func(5); // ok
  b.A::func(); // ok
}
```

O se importen en la clase derivada:

```
struct B : A
{
  using A::func;

  void func(int)
  { }
};
```

Este mecaniso existe como medida de precaución. Se supone que si las dos funciones se llaman igual es porque hacen funciones parecidas... si la clase derivada no declara explícitamente las funciones solapadas existe la posibilidad de que dichas funciones no sean válidas en la función derivada y por eso se ocultan.

Tu caso es similar pero al existir herencia múltiple el compilador no sabe cómo debe actuar: Por parte de B se declara una función `f(int)` y por parte de `C` se declara una función `f()`. En virtud de la ocultación el compilador debería *ocultar* una de las dos funciones... sin embargo ambas están declaradas al mismo nivel a través de la herencia y ahí el compilador se queda sin reglas para priorizar una frente a la otra.

Lo que tienes que hacer es declarar en `D` qué funciones van a estar disponibles:

```
struct D: B, C {
  using C::f; // Importa la función C::f()

  using B::f; // Importa la función B::f(int)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

En la struct C se duplica la función void f() {} heredada en modo virtual, supongo que no se puede duplicar en este caso... Pero puedes usar d.B::f( 5 ); para llamar directamente a la función. Asi que o quitas la función duplicada o la llamas directamente con d.B::f( 5 ); lo que mejor te parezca. Aunque yo no soy de complicarme mucho con las clases te puedes montar un buen lío si no lo tienes todo claro y te haces un buen esquema.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    void f() {}
};

struct B: virtual A {
     void f(int i) {}
};

struct C: virtual A {
    // void f() {} // <- Función duplicada
};

struct D: B, C {

};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    D d;
    d.f(5);
 // d.B::f( 5 ); // Esto si es válido.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aunque la verdad el asunto se las trae, hacer una llamada a la función void f() sí que sería ambigua, pero la función void f(int i) sólo hay una y no debería haber ninguna ambiguedad. Bien pensado no sé porque se produce este error, pero está claro que se confunde con la función void f() de la struct C que nisiquiera es llamada. Un buen dilema.